# What is the safest way to handle different versions of a DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm learning some pandas/ML type stuff. Right now I'm doing a Kaggle tutorial, and the example data we've been given has a bunch of features. I suspect that some of these features are adding noise to the model rather than helping. So, I want to apply several models to the data with all features (as in the tutorial) and record their scores as a baseline. Then, I want to remove one feature at a time, and use the same models on the data without that one feature, and compare the scores.

What's the best way to do this? Naively, I'd just make a different copy of the dataset for each removed feature, but copy() is a little confusing in pandas (in version 0.20, [it says](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) that it makes a deep copy by default, which should be exactly what I want, right? A copy with no connection/reference to the original?). I tried it and it didn't seem to actually be making the copy.

Is there a better way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using for loop.

```
variables = locals()
feature=['A','B','C']
for i in feature:
    variables["dfremoved{0}".format(i)] = df.drop(i,axis=1)

    ''' Do your fit and predict here within the for loop'''
```